# Prove statement about relation of trace and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying linear algebra. I saw on a website the statement that if $\lambda^n+c_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+c_1\lambda+c_0$ is the characteristic polynomial of a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ then $c_{n-1}=-\operatorname{trace}(A)$.

However, no proof was included and I am having a lot of trouble trying to see this.

I tried thinking along the lines of this is equivalent to saying that $-c_{n-1}$= the sum of the eigenvalues of A and tried writing out the definitions of char polynomial etc, but I dont know how else to approach this?

Any suggestions\ is there a common proof for this?

Update: Thank you all for effort, I am just wondering, the level of the site notes were quite a bit below these answers. So is it possible that there is a more simple/algebraic proof to show this? It does not need to be 100% rigoruous

Comment: Think of the trace as the sum of the diagonal entries, and apply the approach you suggest.

Comment: Hmm well , Yes I understand that is what the trace is but I think I am just confused because the cn-1 seems to be so arbitrary at fist glance,

Comment: Sorry, it's a little harder than I initially thought it was. One moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) we know that $-c_{n-1}$ is the sum of the roots of the characteristic polynomial (the eigenvalues of the matrix).

Using the definition of trace we can show that $tr (AB)=tr(BA)$ and from this we find:
$$ Tr (P^{-1}AP)=Tr (APP^{-1})=tr(A)$$ that is: the trace is similarity-invariant.

We can write any matrix A in Jordan canonical form as $A=P^{-1}JP$ where $J$ is an upper triangular matrix with the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ as diagonal elements, so its trace is the sum of the eigenvalues and $tr(A)=tr(J)$ .

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it's clear that it is true when $A$ is a diagonal matrix, and in fact for any upper triangular matrix. So in particular it is true for the Jordan normal form of $A$. Now remember that conjugation preserves trace, and you're done.